# Canvas coordinates system not scaling the same as mouse position

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have now:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-au">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="main-canvas"></canvas>
<button id="settings-button">Settings</button>
<div id="settings-menu">
    <div class="shape-container">
        <label id="shape-size-label" for="shape-size">Shape Size: 50</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="shape-size">
    </div>
    <div class="color-container">
        <label for="square-color">Square Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="square-color" value="#0000ff">
    </div>
    <div class="color-container">
        <label for="circle-color">Circle Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="circle-color" value="#0000ff">
    </div>
    <div class="color-container">
        <label for="rectangle-color">Rectangle Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="rectangle-color" value="#0000ff">
    </div>
    <div class="color-container">
        <label for="triangle-color">Triangle Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="triangle-color" value="#0000ff">
    </div>
    <div class="color-container">
        <label for="canvas-color">Canvas Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="canvas-color" value="#000000">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("main-canvas");
canvas.style.overflow = "hidden";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const settingsButton = document.getElementById("settings-button");
const settingsMenu = document.getElementById("settings-menu");
let mousePos = { x: undefined, y: undefined };
let settingsState = false
let shapeSize = 50
let squareColor = "#0000ff";
let canvasColor = "#000000";

ctx.fillStyle = canvasColor;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);
console.log(screen.width + " " + screen.height)

document.getElementById("settings-button").onclick = function() {
    settingsState =  !settingsState;
    if (settingsState === true) {
        settingsButton.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        settingsMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
        
    }
    else {
        settingsButton.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        settingsMenu.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

document.getElementById("shape-size").onchange = function() {
    let shapeSizeValue = document.getElementById("shape-size");
    let shapeSizeLabel = document.getElementById("shape-size-label");
    shapeSizeLabel.innerHTML = "Shape Size: " + shapeSizeValue.value;
    shapeSize = shapeSizeValue.value
}
document.getElementById("square-color").onchange = function() {
    let squareColorValue = document.getElementById("square-color");
    squareColor = squareColorValue.value
}
document.getElementById("circle-color").onchange = function() {
    let circleColorValue = document.getElementById("circle-color");
}
document.getElementById("rectangle-color").onchange = function() {
    let rectangleColorValue = document.getElementById("rectangle-color");
}
document.getElementById("triangle-color").onchange = function() {
    let triangleColorValue = document.getElementById("triangle-color");
}
document.getElementById("canvas-color").addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    let canvasColorValue = document.getElementById("canvas-color");
    ctx.fillStyle = canvasColorValue.value;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    mousePos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    document.getElementById("settings-button").innerHTML = mousePos.x.toString() + " " + mousePos.y.toString()
});

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.key === "q") {
        console.log("q")
        ctx.fillStyle = squareColor;
        ctx.fillRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, shapeSize/2, shapeSize/2);
        console.log(mousePos.x.toString() + " " + mousePos.y.toString() + " " + shapeSize.toString() + " " + shapeSize.toString());
        console.log(squareColor)
        console.log(screen.width)
    }
    if (event.key === "w") {

    }
    if (event.key === "e") {

    }
    if (event.key === "r") {

    }
}
```

main.css:

```
html, body, #main-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
}
#settings-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    width:10%;
    height:5%;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 160%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0;
}
#settings-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 11%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

If you were to run that you'll find that when you press q, depending on where the mouse is that it will either be outside the viewport or so out that it's just stupid. 0,0 seems to be in the right place but the further you go from 0,0 the worse it gets. Everyone I've talked to is completely clueless as to what is causing this so help would be much appreciated

Comment: Remember to reduce your code to [mcve] form. A lot of the HTML does not contribute to the problem you're solving, same for the CSS and JS. (And of course, the MCVE exercise isn't even "for us", it actually "for yourself" because forcing yourself to remove literally everything that's even remotely unrelated typically brings out the real problem really quickly, and generally reveals both exactly where things are going wrong, _and why_, but in the rare few cases where the why is still unclear you now have perfect code for putting in a question)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to change anything in case it's a combined stream that causing the problem where the elements are interacting and that would be the cause.

Comment: That's _exactly_ when you _should_ run through the [mcve] exercise, because that's what debugging is: you need to find out what code's involved in causing the problem, so that you can then start to look at how to _fix_ the problem. Remember, even if you're going to ask others for help, you're still responsible for figuring out what the smallest amount of code is that still shows off the problem - and usually in doing so you find the problem all on your own, and  you don't even need SO.